# mySQL: apply where clause to all columns and count results by value

Tags: mysql, count, sql-like

I have a mySQL table like this

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|    Col1    |    Col2    |    Col3    |
+------------+------------+------------+
| wor&amp;dA | wordB      | wordC      |
| wordD      | wordE      | wor&amp;dF |
| wordG      | wo&amp;rdH | wordJ      |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

I need to extract all the values of all the columns where a cell contains the `&amp;` value, grouped by the count of each occurrence.

My current approach is this one, converting all the table on a key-value table and apply filters on it.

```
SELECT field, value, count(value) as count FROM (
    SELECT "Col1" as field, Col1 as value FROM myTable
    UNION
    SELECT "Col2" as field, Col2 as value FROM myTable
    UNION
    SELECT "Col3" as field, Col3 as value FROM myTable
) as A
WHERE value LIKE '%&amp;%'
GROUP BY 1,2
```

In the main table I have about 18k records and 41 columns and th execution time is about 36s. The execution time is not the problem here, but the UNION operator seems to keep unique pairs (field-value), so the `GROUP BY` operation is useless

The output I'm looking for is this one. For each field-value pair, the count value (this is needed if I have different values which contains `&amp;` in the same column)

```
+-------+------------+-------+
| field |   value    | count |
+-------+------------+-------+
| Col1  | wor&amp;dA |     1 |
| Col2  | wo&amp;rdH |     1 |
| Col3  | wor&amp;dF |     1 |
+-------+------------+-------+
```

How can this query can be made in order to get the output formatted as the example?

Comment: Try to move `like` statement to inner `union` query?

Comment: So what is your desired output? One row per column (i.e. 41 rows) each with the count of ampersands? Then you won't see any values of course, because there can be different values with ampersands per column. And do you want to count a cell that contains two ampersands once or twice?

Comment: By the way: don't use `UNION` when you really only want `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I edited the main question to better understand. My desired output is the one as the example I provided. `<field-value pair><count value>`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `UNION ALL` worked

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Col1COUNT) Col1COUNT,SUM(Col2COUNT) Col2COUNT,SUM(Col3COUNT) Col3COUNT FROM (
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN COL1 LIKE '%&amp;%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  Col1COUNT ,
    CASE WHEN COL2 LIKE '%&amp;%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  Col2COUNT ,
    CASE WHEN COL3 LIKE '%&amp;%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  Col3COUNT 
    FROM myTable
)Z
;
```

**or**

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Col1VAL) Col1VAL ,SUM(Col1COUNT) Col1COUNT,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Col2VAL) Col2VAL,SUM(Col2COUNT) Col2COUNT,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Col3VAL) Col3VAL,SUM(Col3COUNT) Col3COUNT FROM (
        SELECT 
        CASE WHEN COL1 LIKE '%&amp;%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  Col1COUNT ,
        CASE WHEN COL2 LIKE '%&amp;%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  Col2COUNT ,
        CASE WHEN COL3 LIKE '%&amp;%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  Col3COUNT ,
        CASE WHEN COL1 LIKE '%&amp;%' THEN VALUE END  Col1VAL ,
        CASE WHEN COL2 LIKE '%&amp;%' THEN VALUE END  Col2VAL,
        CASE WHEN COL3 LIKE '%&amp;%' THEN VALUE END  Col3VAL

        FROM myTable
    )Z
    ;
```

Just try above code.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: This works, but only generates the number w/o the values. I need the values as well

Comment: @DevilingMaster How much time it's required?
It's only prints single field.

Comment: The time here is not a problem (it is a background procedure), but my query does not work at the moment. I need to have a working query, slow or fast is not a problem

Answer (score -1):

`UNION` eliminates duplicates, so you count each occurence just once. Use `UNION ALL` instead:

```
SELECT field, value, count(*) as "count" FROM (
    SELECT "Col1" as field, Col1 as value FROM myTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Col2" as field, Col2 as value FROM myTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Col3" as field, Col3 as value FROM myTable
) as A
WHERE value LIKE '%&amp;%'
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: Are you sure it will print value with aggregate function (`count`)?
Unexpected from your end.

Comment: @Sagar Gangwal: I don't know what you mean. If `'wor&amp;dA'` occurs twice in col1, then the field/value pair `'col1'` / `'wor&amp;dA'` gets a count of 2. Exatly what the OP is asking. The only problem the OP had was that the count was always 1 because of `UNION` eliminating duplicates.

Comment: He is asking a count of each column which contains special character or something with value also.
Do you really think your answer satisfy this condition?

Comment: @Sagar Gangwal: Yes. For one thing the `WHERE` clause makes sure I only count strings that contain '&amp;' and for another the OP already ackknowledged that `UNION ALL` works for him (see the request's comments section). I merely posted this answer so it can be accepted and future readers find the solution easily.

Comment: Just think scenario `'col1' / 'wor&amp;dA'` ,`'col1' / 'Thorsten&amp;dA'` and ``'col1' / 'Kettner&amp;dA'``.What your query will print is  `3` and `'wor&amp;dA`. But it wants all three records like `wor&amp;dA``Thorsten&amp;dA` `Kettner&amp;dA`.

Comment: My query will output one row per field/value, which is three rows in your example. Each with a count of 1. If one of them occured twice it would get a count of 2, which is the only difference to the OP's query and the only issue they faced.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142075/discussion-between-sagar-gangwal-and-thorsten-kettner).

Comment: Just see his comment on my answer `This works, but only generates the number w/o the values. I need the values as well `